# process spawning in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, process, spawn

I want to use os.spawn* function to make a upstart service call. The reason to use os.spawn over subprocess is because os.spawn calls provides more control over the way the program is launched though with a little complex call signature.

My command is :

```
sudo start service/new_service db=tmp
```

I am not sure how to run string command using os.spawn* function family.

Comment: Why can't you use `subprocess` for this? Your statement of "More control" is based on what exactly? The `subprocess` module is developed specifically for the needs you require, and the command you detailed in your question is a perfectly normal command to run with `subprocess`.

Comment: I initially used subprocess this way: `subprocess.Popen('sudo start service/new_service db=tmp', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` However even after the child process gets terminated, the calling process dont get terminated.

Answer (score 1):

The *only* 'more control' that `os.spawn` gives you over `subprocess` is the `mode` argument - but on Unix, this can only control whether the call blocks waiting for the subprocess to finish, which is also doable with `subprocess`.

In any case, the best way to turn your command into a list of arguments is to use the [`shlex.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) function, as recommended by the `subprocess` docs:

```
command = 'sudo start service/new_sevice db=tmp'
subprocess.call(shlex.split(command))
```

If you *really* want to use `os.spawn*` family (and you probably don't), you can also use `shlex.split` - it gives its result in the form `subprocess` expects which differs slightly from the form `os.spawn*` expect, but you can get around this easily enough using the `spawnl*` variants and Python's argument unpacking:

```
os.spawnlp(os.P_WAIT, *shlex.split(command))
```

Comment: I can totally go with using subprocess if the main calling process terminates with child process termination, which is not happening in my case. I used this command `subprocess.Popen('sudo start service/new_service db=tmp', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` Yes child process spawning should be nonblocking too.

Comment: @S-T I don't think it would with `os.spawn*` either. The best way to achieve that (since you don't want to block waiting for the child to finish) is likely to check `proc.poll() is not None` occasionally (where `proc` is the return value of `Popen`) - once that condition is true, the child process has stopped. Alternatively, you might want to use the standard `multiprocessing` module to play double fork games - spawn a new Python process whose only job is to block waiting for the spawned `sudo` to finish, and then terminate itself and its parent.